# Is there a way to bind to more than one indexed property in a Xamarin viewmodel?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Is there a way to bind to more than one indexed property in a Xamarin viewmodel?

Indexer argument can be overloaded but the xaml is only going to pass in a string, so I am not sure how more than one indexer can be present in a view model.

for eg:

In the view model class, I have

```
class MyViewModel 
{
   public Slot[] slots;
   public string this[string id]
   {
      get
      {
           return Slots[Convert.ToInt16(id)-1].State;
      }
   }

}


public class Slot
{
    public string State {get;set;}
    public bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
}
```

In XAML, I can use this indexer like this:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding [0]}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding [1]}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding [2]}" />
</StackLayout>
```

If I want to expose another indexed property (IsEnabled in this case) from the same view model, how can I accomplish that?

Indexers can be overloaded, but the XAML code can only pass string types within [], am I right?

-Thanks

Update: changed to a better example

Comment: if Data is a public property, why not just use Data[123]?

Comment: create a public Slots property, and then use Slots[0].Id, Slots[0].State, etc

Comment: In that case, how do I raise the property changed event when the values of State and IsEnabled properties are set in the ViewModel? Thanks

Comment: implement INPC on the Slot class

Comment: Great! Thanks for the guidance.